# On click Ipad browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ipad

all I have small problem. In my gallery page I have function that shows small loader gif on link click, to show loading process while page is redirected. And then I click on Back button i ipad browser it loads me page with that loader displaying, plz help.

Comment: You need to supply the code of what you have attempted.

Answer (score 0):

handle visiblity on page load this will be done on all pages. i.e hide gif image on page load event of jquery.